# Regex matching either or condition with '|' not working

Tags: python, regex

I have some sample text as below:

```
MTG-2022039036 MTG
MTG-LR 3136 / 130 MTG 
MTG-LR 201260 / 9046 ASSIGN
MTG-2021063349 MTG
```

My desired Results:

```
2022039036
3136 / 130
201260 / 9046
2021063349
```

My regex patterns work individually just fine example:

```
match1 = re.search(r'(\d+ \/ ?\d+)', ref)
num1 = match1.group(1) if match1 else None
# correctly returns 3136 / 130

match2 = re.search(r'(?:-?)(\d+)', ref)
num2 = match2.group(1) if match2 else None
# correctly returns 2021063349
```

But I want to combine them in one line like below to match either one or other pattern since only one case will occur in each string:

```
match = re.search(r'(?:-?)(\d+)|(\d+ \/ ?\d+)', ref)
num = match.group(1) if match else None
# This only returns 3136
```

I feel like I'm doing a very simple thing but no idea why now this doesn't work. I have used '|' for matching either or conditions in pandas str.extract() and had no problems there. Please advise.

Comment: try this `(?<=(?:LR\s))(\d+\s\/\s\d+)|(\d+)` and instead of search use `re.findall()` to get all if the string is not divided into lines

Comment: Reverse the order of the subpatterns: `re.search(r'(\d+ \/ ?\d+)|(?:-?)(\d+)', ref)`.  The issue is first subpattern of or matched, so didn't try 2nd.

Comment: Why not use a single pattern? `\b\d+(?: / \d+)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/0PbGjT/1

Comment: @DarrylG You are right. But now I get an extra '-' in front of regular numbers.

Comment: To remove the extra '-' simplify to: `re.search(r'(\d+ \/ ?\d+)|(\d+)', ref)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be an optional space after the `/`, but you might use a single pattern:

```
\b\d+(?: / ?\d+)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?: / ?\d+)?` Optionally match  `/` then an optional space and 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sh6whL/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\d+(?: / ?\d+)?\b"

s = ("MTG-2022039036 MTG\n"
            "MTG-LR 3136 / 130 MTG \n"
            "MTG-LR 201260 / 9046 ASSIGN\n"
            "MTG-2021063349 MTG")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['2022039036', '3136 / 130', '201260 / 9046', '2021063349']
```

---

Or use a capture group matching the leading MTG- with optional LR, where the group 1 value will be returned by `re.findall`

```
\bMTG-(?:LR )?(\d+(?: / \d+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bMTG-` Match literally with a leading word boundary
- `(?:LR )?` Optionally match `LR`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+(?: / \d+)?` Optionally match  `/` then an optional space and 1+ digits
- `)` Close **group 1**
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CV88OM/1)

Comment: On your third bulletpoint, where does the "optionally" come from in this phrase `(?: / ?\d+)?`  Is it the last `?`

Comment: @amnesic Yes that is correct, the questionmark matches 0 or 1 times (optional)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
^MTG-[^0-9]*(\d+(?:\s+/\s+\d+)?)
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ICI9y/1) for above regex.

With Python3 code, please try following, using `findall` function of `re` module and in that using `re.M` flag true for multiline enabling.

```
import re
var="""MTG-2022039036 MTG
MTG-LR 3136 / 130 MTG
MTG-LR 201260 / 9046 ASSIGN
MTG-2021063349 MTG"""

re.findall(r'^MTG-[^0-9]*(\d+(?:\s+/\s+\d+)?)', var, re.M)
['2022039036', '3136 / 130', '201260 / 9046', '2021063349']
```